# Ruby - Regular Expression to allow any Non-ASCII - Chinese characters in URL

Tags: regex, ruby, string, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to write a regex for a URL which contains Chinese characters too. Purpose to write such a regex is whenever a URL containing Chinese characters is encountered, it doesn't match the URL and gives output as no results found.

I have a regex which is working for normal URLs which is as below:

```rb
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$
```

This covers anything which is as for example `www.google.com` but doesn't work for URL like `http://www.詹姆斯.com/`.

I have also tried Ruby's `URI` module for validating the URLs but it doesn't work.

I am using [Rubular](https://rubular.com/) to check my regex.

**Expected**: A regex in `Ruby` which validates any URL including characters in any language(i.e. French, Chinese etc) along with its query string parameters as `http://www.詹姆斯.com/?abc=1234`.

Comment: Try replacing `a-z` with `[:alpha:]` and `\w` with `[:alnum:]_`. If it does not help, try `\p{L}` instead of `a-z` and `\p{L}0-9_` instead of `\w`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks. This worked for the host part only but not for the rest of the URL which can be `www.chinese-char-url.com/?abc=1234`.

Comment: Try `/\A(?:https?:\/\/)?[\d\p{L}_.-]+\.([\p{L}.]{2,6})(?:\/[^\s\/]*)*\/?\z/`

Comment: Or, `/\A(?:https?:\/\/)?[\d\p{L}_.-]+\.([\p{L}.]{2,6})(?:\/[^?#\s\/]*)*(?:[?#]\S*|\/)?\z/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Both of your above options works. But it also matches a URL such as `https://www.abc` which is not a valid URL as `.com` is missing, hence it shouldn't get matched.  I hope you can fix this issue and write as an answer below so that i can approve. Thanks.

Comment: Then try `\A(?:https?:\/\/)?(?!www\.[^\/]*$)[\d\p{L}_.-]+\.([\p{L}.]{2,6})(?:\/[^\s\/]+)*\/?\z`, see https://rubular.com/r/9Wnl7HLoYSg7nT

Comment: Worked !!! Please write the same in answers below so that I can mark it as approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/\A(?:https?:\/\/)?(?!www\.[^\/]*\z)[\d\p{L}_.-]+\.[\p{L}.]{2,6}(?:\/[^\s\/]+)*\/?\z/
```

See the [regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/9Wnl7HLoYSg7nT)

NOTE: To match a whole string with a Ruby regex, you should use `\A` and `\z`, not `^` and `$` that match start and end of any *line*. That is why the demo is different from the final regex posted.

**Pattern details**

- `\A` - start of string
- `(?:https?:\/\/)?` - an optional `http://` or `https://`
- `(?!www\.[^\/]*\z)` - the text that is immediately to the right cannot be `www.` and followed with any 0+ chars other than `/` up to the end of the string
- `[\d\p{L}_.-]+` - 1 or more digit, letter, `_`, `.` or `-` chars
- `\.` - a dot
- `[\p{L}.]{2,6}` - 2 to 6 letters or dots
- `(?:\/[^\s\/]+)*` - 0 or more sequences of `/` and 1+ chars other than whitespace and `/`
- `\/?` - an optional `/`
- `\z` - end of string.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the rest of your regex (the query/path part),  so let me focus just on the host part. You need to use unicode character classes, e.g. `\p{L}` instead of `[a-z]` that is ASCII-only. For instance:

```
'http://www.詹姆斯.com/?abc=1234'.match(/^(https?:\/\/)?([\d\p{L}\.-]+)/)
# => #<MatchData "http://www.詹姆斯.com" 1:"http://" 2:"www.詹姆斯.com">
```

See more in [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties).

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem here is that it should match the query string parameters too. To match only the `host` doesn't solve my problem in this case. Let me know if you have any queries.